# A way to effective check if my image already exists in my SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have pictures in my SQL Server 2008 database and I am checking before I add new picture to DB if it already exists because I don't want to have copy.

Now I am checking it with:

```
If EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 ImageID 
          FROM ImageTable 
          WHERE Image = @Image 
            AND PersonalID = @PersonalID 
            AND CatID = @CatID 
            AND Dev = @Dev 
          ORDER BY ImageID DESC)
```

`Image` is my image in Base64 encoding.

Collecting pictures in the database is not good idea, because I am getting about 2k pictures and more, but my question: is that good way to check if a picture already exists in the database, or maybe there is more effective way?

Comment: So which is it? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Ideally you should be searching based on primary key then seeing if the binary field is set to null or not....

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for either MySQL or SQL Server (I'm not sure which one by the title):

When the program looks at the image, use an algorithm (pretty much any works though MD5 is popular) to computer the checksum or hash for the image. Add another column to your table that will hold said checksum/hash and then use that to check for redundant images.

The problem with image storing, is that a single change to the file will make it "look" unique even if the change has been the same picture but saved in a different file format (jpg, gif, png) from another already in the database.

SQL Server has a function called HASHBYTES() but it only works on the FIRST 8000 bytes, I would stay away from this and use a RDBMS agnostic method.

Comment: So I should add checksum and index for that column?

Comment: Yes, I'd add a column and put and index on it.